Block components corresponding to $A : V \oplus W \to V \oplus W$
I'm looking at the following sentence:

If you have a short exact sequence of vector spaces
$$
0 \to U \to V \to W \to 0
$$
such sequence is always split and after fixing a splitting $V \cong U \oplus W$, if $A$ is a linear map $A : V \to V$, then
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{UU} & A_{UW} \\
A_{WU} & A_{WW}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

and I cannot figure out what these maps $A_{UW}$ and $A_{WU}$ are. How are these things defined?

Discussion on meta which explains the downvotes for the question and the answers: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37988/surrendering-to-the-duplicate-flood

$A_{WU}=P_W\circ (A|_U)$, similarly with $W,U$ reversed.
More generally if $T:V\to W$ is linear and $V=\bigoplus_{j=1}^nV_j$ and $W=\bigoplus_{i=1}^mW_i$ then $T$ has a block decomposition $T=(T_{ij})$, where for $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$ we have $T_{ij}:V_j\to W_i$ is defined to be $P_{W_i}\circ (T|_{V_j}) = P_{W_i}\circ T\circ \iota_{V_j}$, where $P_{W_i}$ is the canonical projection $W\to W_i$ induced by the direct sum, and $\iota_{V_j}:V_j\to V$ is the canonical injection.
In the case where you pick a basis then we get a direct sum into 1D subspaces so you can identify with a number, and that’s how we get the usual matrix representation (in terms of numbers) relative to a basis on the domain and target.

See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37988/surrendering-to-the-duplicate-flood where the downvotes come from

@MartinBrandenburg thanks for the explanation.
